# Sort entire Pivot table in Excel 2013 by column

Tags: sorting, excel-2010, pivot-table, excel-2013, powerpivot

I have a Pivot Table with many columns.

I want the Pivot the ability to sort one of the columns in a way that the whole column is sorted and not the relative position in the hierarchy.

Example:

```
NAME    PRODUCT   SUM
Joe       A       400
Joe       B       200
Joe       B       300
Alice     A       500
Alice     A       200
Alice     C       300
```

If I use the regular sort on the Sum column, I will get the data sorted partially.

```
Alice      A    500
Alice      A    300
Alice      C    200
Joe        A    400
Joe        B    300
Joe        B    200
```

As you can see, the Sum column is sorted only relevant to the Name column.
I want the whole column to be sorted.

Expected result should look something like this:

```
Alice      A    500
Joe        A    400
Alice      C    300
Joe        B    300
Alice      A    200
Joe        B    200
```

Comment: Is this a PowerPivot pivot table? Or just a regular pivot-table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than one field in the row area of the pivot table, you cannot create a sort purely by value. The hierarchy cannot be ignored. That's how a pivot table works. Don't shoot the messenger.

Answer (score 0):

So, essentially, you want to sort the SUM columns first and then the NAME column and last the PRODUCT column.

Have a look in the MSDN [Sort data in a PivotTable](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sort-data-in-a-PivotTable-e41f7107-b92d-44ef-861f-24430830450a), I think that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Add a dummy column in the data set and create an index (1 through the number of rows). If you pull that into the left-most column in your pivot, you'll be able to sort by the field you want. You can hide that column for visual purposes.